# petalinux-package fails to find file in /tmp

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, petalinux

I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/TR2g6pAKRT0?t=487) rather good YT tutorial to build and run petalinux on an arty board. Everything is fine until I try to package the build with petalinux-package.

I get the following error:

```
daniel@daniel-OptiPlex-3050:~/work/arty_petalinux_test$ petalinux-package --boot --force --fpga ../arty_linux/arty_linux.runs/impl_1/design_1_wrapper.bit --u-boot --kernel --flash-size 16 --flash-intf SPIx1
INFO: Sourcing build tools
WARNING: Auto detecting MMI file with XSA
INFO: Creating download.bit...
INFO: Fpga bitstream: /home/daniel/work/arty_linux/arty_linux.runs/impl_1/design_1_wrapper.bit
INFO: Fpga bitstream MMI file: /tmp/tmp.j6IieOwBAR/design_1_wrapper.mmi
INFO: Fsbl file: /home/daniel/work/arty_petalinux_test/images/linux/fs-boot.elf
INFO: Output download.bit: /home/daniel/work/arty_petalinux_test/images/linux/download.bit
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/tmp.j6IieOwBAR/download.bit': No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to create download bit file for MicroBlaze MCS file.
```

The temp directory which it is looking for hasn't been created. I've also tried specifying the path to the MMI file (same as the path to the bit file) explicitly, but same issue.

Does petalinux-package generate any logs? I've searched and find no clue for this odd error.

Any ideas?